# Eclipse Syntax Error on Token with nothing apparently wrong

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've been trying to get this bit of Android code working for a while, and eclipse is giving me the ever so helpful Syntax Error when there shouldn't be one.  I checked my brackets and I have the right number, and I believe they are all where they should be.  This is code copied and pasted from a tutorial, and slightly tweaked.  The code provided, in its entirety, works, but my version of it gives the errors.  I didn't change that much.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

Button Pull_Data; 


// Define the TextViews

TextView client_Address1;
TextView client_Address2;
TextView client_Address3;
TextView client_Id;

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "Address"; // parent node
static final String KEY_PERSON = "addedByPerson";
static final String KEY_CITY = "addressCity";
static final String KEY_LINE_ONE = "addressLineOne";
static final String KEY_LINE_TWO = "addressLineTwo";
static final String KEY_STATE = "addressState";
static final String KEY_TYPE_ID = "addressTypeId";
static final String KEY_ZIP = "addressZip";
static final String KEY_CLIENT_ID = "clientId";
static final String KEY_COUNTRY_CODE = "countryCode";
static final String KEY_OBJECT_ID = "objectId";
static final String KEY_RECORD_ADDED_DATE = "recordAddedDate";
static final String KEY_RECORD_UPDATED_DATE = "recordUpdatedDate";
static final String KEY_RECORD_UPDATED_PERSON = "recordUpdatedPerson";
static final String KEY_SYNC_STATUS = "syncStatus"; //Syntax error is flagged here

// XML Data to Retrieve
Address = "";
addedByPerson = "";
addressCity = "";
addressLineOne = "";
addressLineTwo  = "";
addressState  = "";
addressTypeId  = "";
addressZip = "";
clientId = "";
countryCode = "";
objectId = "";
recordAddedDate = "";
recordUpdatedDate = "";
recordUpdatedPerson = "";
syncStatus = "";



// Holds values pulled from the XML document using XmlPullParser
String[][] xmlPullParserArray = {{"Address", "0"},{"addedByPerson", "0"},{"addressCity", "0"},{"addressLineOne", "0"},{"addressLineTwo", "0"},
    {"addressState", "0"},{"addressTypeId", "0"},{"addressZip", "0"},{"clientId", "0"},
    {"countryCode", "0"},{"objectId", "0"},{"recordAddedDate", "0"},{"recordUpdatedDate", "0"},
    {"recordUpdatedPerson", "0"},{"syncStatus", "0"}};


int parserArrayIncrement = 0;

// END OF NEW STUFF


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ //Another error here, tagged at the first paren after onCreate
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

I have no clue what could be wrong.  Structurally the code hasn't changed.  The first error by static final String KEY_SYNC_STATUS = "syncStatus"; is a Synatx Error on token ";", { expected after this token

The two errors on the OnCreate method are Syntax Error on token "(" expected ; and Syntax Error on token ")" expected ;    Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where are the close square brackets to end onCreate and the Activity?

Comment: The brackets are all present and correct, I counted them and double checked (just didn't include the 300 lines of code here for readability)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
// XML Data to Retrieve
Address = "";
addedByPerson = "";
addressCity = "";
```

Your missing the types. What is Address, a String? What is addedByPerson?

```
// XML Data to Retrieve
String Address = "";
String addedByPerson = "";
String addressCity = "";
...
```

Comment: they are all strings.  For some reason I thought they were defined already.  Doesn't help that eclipse doesn't realize that they are the problem and points to the lines above them.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is this? It is not valid parts of Java class:

```
//XML Data to Retrieve
Address = "";
```

Eclipse has it's own compiler that tries to compile file by parts. It is called incremental compiler.
Maybe it just can not split your class to compilable blocks? Try to solve these problems.